# Items in menu not showing action bar, rather being displayed without any icons in three dots

Tags: java, android, xml

Previously my app name was being displayed hence I had to use `getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false)` to remove the text, but now in its place a blank action is displayed with three dots on the side showing the list items that I have defined.

I want Refresh and Back actions to be displayed directly into the action bar with their respective icons

eventdetails.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:app="schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_refresh"
        app:showAsAction="always"
        android:title="Refresh"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_refresh"
        />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:title="Settings"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
        >
    </item>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_back"
        android:title="Back"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_back"
        app:showAsAction="always"
        />

</menu>
```

EventDetails.java

```java
public class EventDetails extends AppCompatActivity {
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_event_details);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbarEventDetails);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);

}

@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater menuInflater = getMenuInflater();
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.eventdetails, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch(item.getItemId()){
            case R.id.action_back:
                Intent action_back = new Intent(EventDetails.this, EventView.class);
                startActivity(action_back);
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Action Bar]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your **xmlns:app** is not setup properly
change:

```
xmlns:app="schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```

to

```
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```

Comment: @rut_0_1 mark the answer  as correct if it helps...thankx